# Get length of object by nested object id?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm currently using underscore to the length of an object using `_.size(obj)` and that is fine but I'm wondering how I could go a little deeper and get the length of objects who's id's equal `123` in my example. I'm not sure if this is something that can be achieved by using underscore or do I need to use a for..in loop and make some kind of count?

**JS**
console.clear();

```
var obj = {
    'ABC': {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Sesame Street'
    }, 
    'DEF': {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Sesame Street'
    }, 
    'GHI': {
        id: '456',
        name: 'Nowhere Street'
    }
};

console.log('Get length of obj', _.size(obj));
console.log('Get length of obj with id == 123??');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/0yam33ow/

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your object into an array and use `.filter` to get the items with only the id `123`:

```
var arr = _.values(obj);
var newObj = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.id === '123';
});

console.log(_.size(newObj)); // 2
```

You can do the same thing by using underscores `_.where`:

```
var newObj = _.where(obj, {id: '123'});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/0yam33ow/2/)